# How to get the number of entires in SmartSheet using JAVA

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I'm working with **smartsheet** and the problem I'm facing that I want to know whether it's crossed the maximum limit, i.e, 5000 or not before getting 400 BAD request so I can change the sheet.
can any one help me out with this thanks in advance. 
Solution required in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't an API operation that allows you to just request specifically the count of rows in a sheet, you'll need to submit a [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?java#get-sheet) request for the sheet, and then evaluate the value of the `totalRowCount` property in the response.

To minimize the size of the response, you should set the `page` parameter to `1` and the `pageSize` parameter to `1` in the **Get Sheet** request. This'll make it so that only 1 row of data is included in the response (instead of the default behavior, which would return 100 rows of data).

The page in the docs I've linked to above contains a code sample for how to submit a **Get Sheet** request using the Smartsheet Java SDK -- but you'll need to additionally include the 2 parameters as I've described above.

*(Note: I edited this answer on 3/13 to include info about the approach described below by @timwwells' comment. Thanks, Tim!)*

Comment: I would just request the first page with a page size of 1 (query parameters `page` and `pageSize`). That way you'll only get back a single row, but the `totalRowCount` will still contain the total row count for the sheet (not the total row count of the response). The Java SDK takes `page` and `pageSize` arguments to the `getSheet` call.

Comment: Good suggestion, Tim -- I'll update the answer accordingly!